# Website needs a location while webscraping

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having some trouble figuring out why I can't scrape the price off of Lowes website.  The commented text below are attempts at grabbing the price that I've already tried.  The price grabber that I'm currently using prints "Enter your location" leading me to believe that I have to feed the website my location in order to grab the price.  What would you do to counteract this?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=2x4'

r = requests.get(url)

html = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

product_container = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'product-wrapper-right'})

i = 0

for product in product_container:
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(product), 'lxml')

    productName = product.div.a.p.text
    print(productName)

    priceContainer = soup2.find("div", {"class":"product-pricing"})
    productPrice = priceContainer.div.text
    print(productPrice)

    productURL = product.div.a.get('href')
    print("lowes.com" + productURL)
    i = i+1


    #productPrice = product.div.div.span.text
    #print(productPrice)

    #soup3 = soup2.find('div', {"class":"product-pricing"})
    #productPrice = soup3.div.span.text
    #print(productPrice)

    #step1 = product.find_all('div')[1]
    #step2 = step1.find_all('div')[1]
    #productPrice = step2.span.text
    #print(productPrice)
```

All of the commented text has also failed to grab the price with varying degrees.  I expect each of these to print the price, but they all return brackets, the words "Enter your location", the word "None".

Comment: Seems like the page is dynamically created. I tried to find the request url API to see if you can POST a location of sorts, but was unable to find that. You could try to use something like Selenium though, as that might do the trick.

Comment: @chitown88, Thanks for the advice.  I'll look into incorporating that into the program.